# How to change color of the font while overlapping an image?

Tags: javascript, css, text

I saw this site the other day https://bahaasamir.me and I was wondering how this text effect can be reproduced? I mean to change the black color to white while overlapping an image (CSS or JS). I've tried to use blending modes but the outcome wasn't as near as good. Any insights or directions on how this effect could be achieved?

Comment: I inspected the element, and they used a canvas which they drew shapes upon, using javascript.

Comment: Thanks @RickardElimää ... yeah, that's why I asked in the first place is there any other method to achieve that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options . You can choose to write the script and css animations yourself or you could use a library

[animejs](https://animejs.com/)

another option is to use CSS animations

```css
.element {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: stretch;
  animation-duration: 1.5s; 
  animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes stretch {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.3);
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Just check for CSS text animations

```css
@import "compass/css3";

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Finger+Paint);

body {
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 5vw/100vh "Finger Paint";
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 whitesmoke;
  animation: smoky 5s 3s both;
}

span:nth-child(even){
  animation-name: smoky-mirror;
}

@keyframes smoky {
  60% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px whitesmoke;
  }
  to {
    transform:
      translate3d(15rem,-8rem,0)
      rotate(-40deg)
      skewX(70deg)
      scale(1.5);
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px whitesmoke;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes smoky-mirror {
  60% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px whitesmoke; }
  to {
    transform:
      translate3d(18rem,-8rem,0)
      rotate(-40deg) 
      skewX(-70deg)
      scale(2);
     text-shadow: 0 0 20px whitesmoke;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@for $item from 1 through 21 {
  span:nth-of-type(#{$item}){ 
    animation-delay: #{(3 + ($item/10))}s; 
  }
}
```

```html
<span>C</span><span>S</span><span>S</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>S</span><span>m</span><span>o</span><span>k</span><span>y</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>T</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>E</span><span>f</span><span>f</span><span>e</span><span>c</span><span>t</span>
```

[Free Examples](https://freefrontend.com/css-text-animations/)

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/

After reading your question again I found this to contrast text on the image  backgrounds ...

There are a few pens with it so as you animate over a clip-path you can change the color

Comment: Hi @JonoJames, thank you but actually, I've tried that already and it's similar but not exactly the same. What I'd like to achieve is change color to the opposite in case of image 0 to 1 without any additional shades (or any other component in that matter). Currently, I'm experimenting with copying the text and aligning it with the parent one with overflow hidden on it.